# Redirect to Login.aspx Page from Web-Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, asp.net-web-api

I have a Login.aspx page where I use Forms Authentication to login to the site. I use a cookie to store the additional user data and in the next page I use Asynchronous web-api calls to get some data. In the process I read the cookie and the user data. If the user data is found I proceed and if not I want to logout the user and redirect them to login page. I have the following code but the execution of the web-api call continues.

```
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

How do I make the user log out and redirect to login page when I know that the cookie is not found?

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the cookie before you make the Web API calls.

- If the cookie exists and is valid, call the service.
- If the cookie doesn't, redirect to the login page.
- In your API, check for the cookie in the call. If the cookie does not exist, return a 401 unauthorized response code in your web api response.